# How to move to next iteration in for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, button, iteration, continue

I get users to do the following to adjust the luminance of grey squares through [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/) (allowing both big and small changes and registering these values).

```
while exitDemo == false
    [keyIsDown,secs, keyCode] = KbCheck;

    if keyCode(escapeKey)
        exitDemo = true;
    elseif keyCode(more_lum_small)
        rectColor = rectColor + smallcolorchange;
    elseif keyCode(less_lum_small)
        rectColor = rectColor - smallcolorchange;
    elseif keyCode(more_lum_large)
        rectColor = rectColor + bigcolorchange;
    elseif keyCode(less_lum_large)
        rectColor = rectColor - bigcolorchange;
    end

    if keyCode(more_lum_small)
        colorcounter = colorcounter + 0.001;
    elseif keyCode(less_lum_small)
        colorcounter = colorcounter - 0.001;
    elseif keyCode(less_lum_large)
        colorcounter = colorcounter - 0.1;
    elseif keyCode(more_lum_large)
        colorcounter = colorcounter + 0.1;
    end

    centeredRect = CenterRectOnPointd(baseRect, squareX, squareY);
    centeredRect2 = CenterRectOnPointd(baseRect2, square2X, square2Y);
    banner_break = CenterRectOnPointd(banner, bannerX, bannerY);

    % Draw the rect to the screen
    Screen('FillRect', window, rectColor, centeredRect);
    Screen('FillRect', window, rect2Color, centeredRect2);
    Screen('FillRect', window, bannerColor, banner_break);

    % Flip to the screen
    vbl  = Screen('Flip', window, vbl + (waitframes - 0.5) * ifi);
end
```

I now would like to put this in a for loop. Ideally, the user would move to the next iteration by pressing a key or the mouse button.

I am somehow stuck. Should I use a `continue` function?

Comment: I'm confused. You don't have a `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry: I would like to put this in a for loop, where I can move to the next iteration by a click.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to run this type of test on your users multiple times in a for-loop. I don’t want to install Psychtoolbox just to answer one question so I thought I'll mock up my own example with 3 question quiz. You can stop said quiz by answering `q` (quit) to any of the questions. I presume that this would be your application.

```
%% Initialise questions and answers
prompts = {...
    'What instrument did Sherlock Holmes play?';
    'How do we get rid of the pigeons form the roof?';
    'What did you bring me this time minion!?!'};
answers = {...
    'trumpet';
    'bazooka';
    'window'};
no_responses = {...
    'Hmm, interesting... "%s" you say...?\n';
    'Madness! "%s" will never work!\n';
    'Yes! Now that the "%s" is complete, people will tremble at my masters plan!\n'};
yes_responses = {...
    'Splendid! That''s correct\n';
    'Yes... This might work\n';
    'Nooo...!!! The light! It burns!\n'};
completion_message = 'Level up!';

%% Ask questions
exitDemo = false;
for j = 1:numel(no_responses)
    fprintf('--- Question %d ---\n',j);

    response = no_responses{j};
    prompt = sprintf('%s\n>',prompts{j});

    % Loop while has not gotten a correct answer yet
    gotCorrectAnswer = false;
    while ~gotCorrectAnswer
        answer = input(prompt,'s');
        answer = lower(answer);

        if strcmp(answer,'q') % Check for exit condition
            exitDemo = true;
            break
        elseif strcmp(answer,answers{j}) % Check for the correct answer
            fprintf(yes_responses{j});
            gotCorrectAnswer = true;
        else
            fprintf(no_responses{j},answer);
        end
    end

    % Check whether broke out of the for loop due to exit condition
    if exitDemo
        break
    end
end

if ~exitDemo
    fprintf(completion_message);
end
```

Note that you could achieve the same effect by pressing `Ctrl+C` on your keyboard while the code is executing. You can e.g. stop code like `while true; pause(1); end` with this. You don't need to program in any explicit stop conditions. Having said that, that is a bit of a hacky solution and it will abort every part of code which is running. The explicit exit condition allows you to handle exit a bit more gracefully (e.q. close up files, write to log, display a message etc.). Also; you should be aware that your users could possibly do that if they're malicious (unless Psychtoolbox protects against that which I doubt).

Answer (score 0):

answer for keypress:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311250/5841680; based on `input()`

answer for mouseclick:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitforbuttonpress.html; based on `waitforbuttonpress`

you don't need a `for` loop, works in a `while` loop all the same.

hope I did understand the question properly...